# get undefined in first render and cant get data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

in this code I got undefined in first render but after that I can get the data

what is the problem?

action

```
export const getPlanPackage = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const { data } = await getMyPlan();
  return await dispatch({ type: "SET_PLAN_PACKAGE", payload: data.data });
};
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
  planPackage: [],
};

export const packagesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_PLAN_PACKAGE":
      return {
        ...state,
        planPackage: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
  const { planPackage } = useSelector((state) => state.packagesReducer);

  const getDefaultOption = () => {
    switch (planPackage?.month) {
      case 1:
        return 0;
      case 6:
        return 1;
      case 12:
        return 2;
      default:
        return planPackage?.month;
    }
  };

  // OPTIONS
  const [userPackage, setUserPackage] = useState(
    userOptions[getDefaultOption()] || userOptions[0]
  );
```

```
  console.log(getDefaultOption());
 result >>>>
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
1
1
1
1
```

So here I want to get a number from `getDefaultOption()` But when I refresh the page it gave me undefiend at first and I cant get the number and showing the data

Comment: Is the number coming from a server response at const { data } = await getMyPlan(); ?

Comment: What calls `getPlanPackage`?  Also, you don't need to `await` your `dispatch`.  You don't even need to `return` it really, but that's up to you.

Comment: @epicmau5time Yes

Comment: @jmargolisvt its call some information from the server and inside that I can got a number that I need to use it in those codes

Answer (score 1):

I am going for a swing in the dark as I cant see the rest of your code, but it looks like month simply does not exist until it comes back from the server.

Your initial state is an empty array but the server returns an object with a month property instead  if I am seeing correctly?

In that case you could either A, set the `initialState` an object with a similar state to what you expect back from the server but with a value of your choosing like so:

```
const initialState = {
  planPackage: { month: 1 }, //set the initial value here
};
```

Or later in your code it looks like you want to perform a fall back here `userOptions[getDefaultOption()] || userOptions[0]`. In which case since you have your initial state as an array, unless you do `planPackage?.length` on the first call it will never be nullish.

This `[] === true` as is this `[1,2] === true` however this is false `[]?.length === false` but this is true `[1,2]?.length === true`. I used `?.length` because as I said it looks like you're getting back an object from `const { data } = await getMyPlan();` and not an array, and objects don't have the length prototype.

So based on that you may want to do something like this?

```
const [userPackage, setUserPackage] = useState(
    typeof getDefaultOption() === 'undefined' ? userOptions[0] : userOptions[getDefaultOption()]
);
```

Here we definily check if you get anything back from `getDefaultOption()` before passing it to `userOptions` because in it's current form `userOptions[getDefaultOption()] // undefined` will not fall back to `||  userOptions[0]`. The check needs to be performed before being passed to `userOptions[0]`